# Поиск в массиве данных Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

Я хочу сделать приложение, что-то вроде подбора фильма для просмотра по параметрам. То есть пользователь указывает некоторые данные, типа фильм не старше 2005 года, рейтинг imdb не ниже 8 и т.п. А приложение отображает все фильмы, которые подходят под эти параметры.

Меня интересует как мне хранить базу фильмов внутри приложения (приложение должно работать оффлайн) CoreData, массивы или что? И с помощью какого инструмента реализовывать поиск по заданным параметрам?

Нужна помощь в какую сторону мне гуглить?

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы хранить базу данных в виде базы данных? )

Comment: Кстати, сразу задумайтесь об обновлении данных.

Comment: вот это явно опросник

Answer (score 1):

Начать можно с sqlite3 (библиотека libsqlite3.dlyb), если надо что то более продвинутое, то CoreData. Под coredata есть много хороших библиотек, которые облегчают работу с ней - например [magical record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)